# How do I get an outline specification in Java JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I'm looking for the ability to nest JUnit tests. I found @RunWith(Enclosed.class), but it only runs one level inclosed and other tests aren't run.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer over here: [NitorCreations Nested Runner](https://github.com/NitorCreations/CoreComponents/tree/master/junit-runners)

This is exactly what I was looking for. It allows JUnit tests to be fully nested.

Comment: That's a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because NestedRunner tests did not properly visualize test names in my IntelliJ IDEA I am using [HierarchicalContextRunner](https://github.com/bechte/junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner/wiki) instead

It provides exactly the same functionality. Just swap them in the `@RunWith` if you are not happy with how your IDE is showing your tests.

Here is an example of what was wrong:

```
@RunWith(NestedRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void haveARegularTestsInside() {}

    public class hasASubClass {
        @Test
        public void thatHasTests() {}
    }
}
```

looks like this:

[image]

Here I expected to have thatHasTests at the last line, but got the whole AClass$hasASubClass.thatHasTests.

change @RunWith to HierarchicalContextRunner and what you get is now this:

[image]

Better, isn't it?